# Apply function on unlimited parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I would like to write a function that can get unlimited parameters with this syntax

myfunc arg1 arg2  arg3 ....
I have tried some using curring but nothing helped
i have tried to make it recursivly but then scala compiler says:
"scala recursive method needs result type"
Recursive :

```
def func(x:Int) = {
  doSomething(x); myVal:Int=>func(myVal)
}
```

thanks for helpers

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a list of parameters instead of just an unknown number of parameters?

Comment: I don't see how that code could compile. `val` is a reserved word in Scala (unless you enclose it in back-ticks). As for that diagnostic, it should be self-explanatory. Directly recursive methods cannot rely on type inference to get the method result type; you must give it explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Easy:

```
scala> class FRP1 { def apply(args: Int*) = args.mkString("{", ", ", "}") }
defined class FRP1

scala> val frp11 = new FRP1
frp11: FRP1 = FRP1@147611bd

scala> frp11(1)
res0: String = {1}

scala> frp11(1, 2)
res1: String = {1, 2}

scala> frp11(1, 2, 3)
res2: String = {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: this is not what i wanted, i do know about the Int*
i wanted to create a "cool syntax" for my code without using any brackets at all!!
as i said : myFunc arg1 arg2 arg3 .....

Answer (score 6):

So the function you seek takes an argument of a certain type and must return a function which takes an argument of the same type and returns a function with takes an argument of the same type and so on, ad infinitum.

The problem here is that the type of this function is something on the lines of:

```
T[X] = X => T[X]
```

That is, it is a recursive, self-referencing type. Because it is self referencing we must name it for the sole purpose of reusing it within itself (Unfortunately, Scala has no fixed-point combinator for infinite types). Let's call it `InfCurry` and it looks something like this:

```
trait InfCurry[T] extends (T => InfCurry[T])
```

As you can see, it mimics the above definition quite well (another option would have been type aliases, but Scala doesn't support recursive type-aliases).

Let's also define a constructor method to help use define our infinitely curried functions:

```
object InfCurry {
  def apply[T](f: T => InfCurry[T]): InfCurry[T] = new InfCurry[T] {
    def apply(x: T) = f(x)
  }
}
```

With this little tool you can define stuff like this:

```
val f: InfCurry[Int] = InfCurry { x =>
  println(x)
  f
}
```

And you would use this little thing like this:

```
val g = f(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)
g(8)(9)(10)(11)(12)
```

Probably in this case you would like to use method with variable number of arguments - see the other answer - but this is what you asked.

Comment: my purpose for this is to make my syntax more friendly.
i have got 2 many brackets here and i cannot remove them.
so i cannot do : myFunc arg1 arg2 arg3 .....

Comment: can i use implicit to create such a syntax?
if so how?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't obtain this Haskell-like syntax in Scala. You can get read of parenthesis only in this special case: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/118. But that wouldn't work in your case because `myFunc arg1 arg2 arg3` would be interpreted as `myFunc.arg1(arg2).arg3()` which is something completely different. Also, implicits can't help you here.