# Scala function that returns same function

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a function whose return type is not just a function (`A=>B`), but the same function. Here is an example:

```
trait Command

type Config = Command => Command

def addCommand(c: Command): Config = {
  addCommand _
}
```

The above seems to be ok, but it gives this compile error:

```
found   : Command => Command
required: Command
```

Is there way to repair this thing?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve. `addCommand` has a return type of a `Command => Command` function, however you are trying to return `addCommand` which has a type of `Command => (Command => Command)`. What would you like the function returned from `addCommand` to do? What is a significance of `c`? (it isn't being used in your example)

Comment: 2 theon: return type of a `addCommand` is not very imoprtant for me. I want to write like this `addCommand(cmnd1)(cmnd2)(cmnd3)...` and I not care how this chain would stop. What about `c`? I would like to do some bad things and change the global state, add this `c` to mutable collection or smth like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply function on unlimited parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686606/apply-function-on-unlimited-parameters)

Comment: yep! this is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

How about currying?

```
scala> val ac: Command => Config = cm => confCom => confCom
ac: Command => (Command => Command) = <function1>

scala> val c: Config = ac(new Command {})
c: Command => Command = <function1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But it's the deep of the night now here. I'll think about this at morning.